# Are there any tools to test MTD/JFFS2 for Linux 2.4 kernels

Tags: linux, memory, utilities, flash-memory

I have some issues with a platform I support and I suspect memory problems. I wanted to check the Flash parts using some MTD JFFS2 test tools, I found a link to a bunch [on this site.](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/archive/index.html)

However they note that support really isn't there for 2.4 and as stated on that site:

> The MTD community is neither able nor interested to provide support for ancient kernels. Either move yourself and update to a recent kernel.

As upgrading isn't an option for me, I'm trying to find out if there are any other tools that could be used to test Flash memory in Linux on older kernels.

Comment: Also on this page have additional information: 

If you are using 2.4 kernel, that's probably because you're interested in stablity - it is old and long-tested code. Then you should use the original JFFS2 code which is part of the 2.4 kernel. It's old and slow and doesn't support NAND flash, but it is stable, and is maintained.

What type of flash you want to test NOR or NAND? Some additional information about kernel (dmesg or bootlog), supported and used filesystems.
I think that some of mtd-utils may be used out of box from repo, they not depends on kernel version, but depends on mtd driver.